# Game Services Alert in Notification Bar, but no call to onTurnBasedMatchUpdated()?

Tags: android, google-play-services

When I call takeTurn(), I will get a call to onTurnBasedMatchUpdated() on the same device that called takeTurn(). But I will not get the call to onTurnBasedMatchUpdated() on the other device that is waiting for its turn. Instead, Game Services will alert the device that it is their turn to play in the notification bar. I was hoping that, if the device remained in-game, that the game would continue to catch onTurnBasedMatchUpdated() when the other player calls takeTurn(). So how do I prevent the notification and simply handle the call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mannan pointed out, it is onTurnBasedMatchReceived() that is called when an opponent takes their turn. It is also called when an opponent connects to your match for the first time. While this function is required to be defined for an "OnTurnBasedMatchUpdatedListener" it is not actually called for that listener. You must ALSO implement "OnTurnBasedMatchUpdateReceivedListener". Further, after implementing it, you must then REGISTER it (I do so after signing in) with getGamesClient().registerMatchUpdateListener(this). Seriously though, where is all the documentation for this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When a player's turn is arrived, following callback is called,

```
onTurnBasedMatchReceived(TurnBasedMatch match)
```

and in this callback, you can get info about the turn and its data from match parameter.

I still dont know why onTurnBasedMatchUpdated() is not called.

Comment: Interesting. I could have sworn I was printing a log statement for every one of those and none of them triggered. I'll recheck later. This function returns void though so I presume it won't consume the call and thus the notification will still occur in the Notification Bar?

Comment: This function is definitely triggered on Android 4.4.2 with play-services library version 4.1.32 978161-30. But it is not triggered on Android 4.0.3 with play-services library version 4.1.32 978161-34. What Android and play-services library version are you using?

Comment: It's definitely not triggering onTurnBasedMatchReceived. It's running Android 4.2.2 with library 4.1.32 (978161-30). My other device is running Android 4.1.2 and it's not triggering the function either.

Comment: Some strange updated information: While staring at my screen wondering what the problem is, someone called the phone that was waiting for the notification. I ignored it. Once the call disappeared, the update occurred! Why did it need a phone call??